# Calculating R-square of a slope of specific part of a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, scipy, curve-fitting

As a tradition, I want to say that I am pretty new to python.

I have set of x and y values as csv file, and my y values are pretty noisy. So far, I managed to use a filter(scipy.signal.savgol_filter) to filter the noise, plot my graph, and get a linear regression of my data, where it is showing a linear trend. This part is important, because my question is related to linear fitting of some part of the data. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal
import os
from scipy.signal import savgol_coeffs
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from scipy.linalg import lstsq

plt.rc('lines',linewidth=1)
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=16)
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=14)
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=14)
plt.rc('legend', fontsize=10)

# define material parameters
deprate = 5.90E-07
 #deposition rate unit: cm/s
Ms = 180000 # Si substrate modulus, unit: MPa
hs = 0.03 # Si substrate thickness, unit: cm
stressfac = Ms*hs**2/6 # stress prefactor, unit: MPa 

def fit_slope(hfilm, curvature, h0, h1):
# use least square fitting to find the slope of the film_thickness vs curvature curve btw 
# thickness = h0 and h1.
# return fitting parameter p. Least square fitting line is y = p[1]*x + p[0]
    xdata = hfilm[ (hfilm>h0) & (hfilm<h1)]
    ydata = curvature[(hfilm>h0) & (hfilm<h1)]
    A = xdata[:, np.newaxis] ** [0,1]
    p, *_ = lstsq(A, ydata)
    return p

def read_MOSSdata(filename, deprate): 
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\s*,\s*', engine='python') 
    time = data['time [s]'][~data['time [s]'].isna()].to_numpy()
    curvature = data['Curvature'][~data['time [s]'].isna()] # curvature unit: 1/cm
    hfilm = time * deprate # file thickness unit: cm
    return time, hfilm, curvature 

filename = (r'C:\Users\yavuz\01-0722-2.csv')
time, hfilm, curvature = read_MOSSdata(filename, deprate)
h0 = 0.00005
h1 = 0.00008                
xdata = np.linspace(h0, h1, 500)
yhat = scipy.signal.savgol_filter(curvature, 21,1)
p = fit_slope(hfilm, yhat, h0, h1)
plt.plot(hfilm, curvature)
plt.plot(hfilm, yhat, color='red', label = 'filtered data')
plt.plot(xdata, p[1]*xdata + p[0], color='green', linewidth=4, label = 'linear fitting')
plt.xlabel("Film thickness (cm)")
plt.ylabel("Curvature(1/cm)")
print(f'fitted stress = {-p[1]*stressfac} MPa')
plt.legend(loc=0)
```

[image: my graph]

My question is how do I calculate R-square value of this slope on my graph? I tried using r-square value calculators like sklearn.metrics but the problem is that I am limiting my x values to get a slope of a window, and all of the codes I tried, showing the problem of ''expected x and y to have same length''. I would add the csv file but it seems like there is not such an option. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: [`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) returns among other values the r-value. I for one would use it on unfiltered data.

Comment: I tried it too and same issue, I think my problem is specifying a window to get R square value

Comment: Thank you for the follow up! I am not sure if there is a way to send you the data, or attach it to my post. I think the problem is not with the filter, because I can't get a R-square for my non-filtered data either (for the slope)

Comment: Not really necessary. Slice `hfilm` and `curvature` (or `yhat` if you want to fit on filtered data) for `h0` and `h1` as you did in `fitslope()`. They should be two 1-D numpy arrays of the same length (check). If they are, feed them into `linregress`, voila. If not, well that would be a surprise as you can plot them as x-y pairs and matplotlib would complain if they had different lengths.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean, in fact I was looking for a solution of this!! (I did not know that it is called ''slicing''.) So now my question would be how I slice data the specifically the part where I have a slope? Let's say I want to slice between h0 and h1 on x axis, but I would not know what the corresponding points on y-axis(unless I check them one by one)

Comment: But you already used this method with `hfilm[(hfilm>h0) & (hfilm<h1)]`. For [Boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), you don't need to provide explicitly the slice indexes - `print((hfilm>h0) & (hfilm<h1))` shows you why it has this name. So, for your regression you have `hfilm[(hfilm>h0) & (hfilm<h1)]` as the x-data and `curvature[(hfilm>h0) & (hfilm<h1)]` as the corresponding y-data.

Comment: @Mr.T Please add your comment as an answer to this post as it solved OP's problem.